# Comparing logit estimates across surveys

Tags: logistic, survey

I'm estimating adjusted odds-ratios from two separate, nationally-representative surveys. I'd like to conduct hypothesis testing on the estimates, to test if there is a detectable, statistical difference between them. I've used between sample z test for means, but what is the most appropriate approach for comparing logit coefficients derived from surveys? The surveys have different designs and weighting.

If it helps formulate your answer, I'm using R.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with reporting the ORs and their respective 95% CIs. If the tails of either CI doesn't overlap the respective estimate, you can reject the null that they are the same. This works under the assumption that the surveys are independent, and is of reduced power if they are not independent.

Comment: If you have original data from two surveys, try to fit one model by using dummy variable. It is nearly impossible to compare something getting from two models built on the different data.